# How to change the contents of a form

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have a form made in C# that has two text boxes and a button. what I want to know is there a way to when the button is clicked. Change the layout of the original form to just having one text box and a button. They would be completely different from the original text box and button just to let you know.

Comment: Will hiding the controls and unhiding the controls not work? I think that should be easy

Comment: check out this article http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manipulate-instances-of-windows-forms-in-c/1053742

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: And what does `completely different from the original text box and button` mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like following code you can change the layouts of form contents

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Visible = false; // to hide textbox
    button1.Size = new Size(60, 20);// for changing button layouts
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily remove the original controls and then add new controls.

I believe the following should answer your question without all of the negative diatribe.

```
    private void btnThatGetsClicked_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Remove the existing controls.
        this.Controls.Remove(this.textBox1);
        this.Controls.Remove(this.textBox2);
        this.Controls.Remove(this.btnThatGetsClicked);

        //Create the new controls.
        TextBox TextBox_New = new TextBox();
        Button Button_New = new Button();

        //Add the new controls to this form.
        this.Controls.Add(TextBox_New);
        this.Controls.Add(Button_New);
    }
```